# how to save the return value of a function to a file

Tags: python, function, numpy

i have a function that takes arrays as input and does some calculation.Now i want to save the return value to a text file using np.savetxt or any otherway...while doing i am getting error "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

i defined the function as below now i want to save the return z value to a file and want to use it later for different task

```
def cal(a,b,c)
   z=a+b+c
   return  z
x=print(cal(a,b,c))
np.savetxt('test',x)
```

can anybody suggest a solution...Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to replace `x=print(cal(a,b,c))` with `x=cal(a, b, c)`? Can you share your full code with the array?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to save the `print` result to a variable instead of the function result, edit your code as follow:

```
import numpy as np

def cal(a,b,c):
   z=a+b+c
   return  z

a = [1, 2]
b = [1, 2]
c = [1, 2]

x=cal(a, b, c)

np.savetxt('test',x)
```

Here is the output file generated:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
```

If you pass three list as argument to the function it will return an 1D array so `np.savetxt` can work.

---

There are different ways to save to a `.txt` file, in this case you have to format the output to respect the `numpy` function request. Here you can see an example to save the file using the `open` method:

```py
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('myLineToWrite')
```

Open the file using the `with` automatically close it after the writing.

---

You can also use the `print()` function to write to the file:

```py
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    print(positionStr, file=myFile, flush=False)
```

This is because the `print()` is defined as `print(object(s), sep=separator, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)` where:

- `object(s)`: Any object, and as many as you like. Will be converted to string before printed
- `sep='separator'`: Optional. Specify how to separate the objects, if there is more than one. Default is `' '`
- `end='end'`: Optional. Specify what to print at the end. Default is `'\n'` (line feed)
- `file`: Optional. An object with a write method. Default is `sys.stdout`
- `flush`: Optional. A Boolean, specifying if the output is flushed (`True`) or buffered (`False`). Default is `False`

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP meant, using this function with lists simply appends all lists together.

Comment: let me check friend

Comment: @snatchysquid This is what is code does, maybe is better if he change the request including the list and the desired output

Comment: how to pass list i want to pass array values

Comment: I thought, and still think, he wants to pass values, ints or strs, for example

Comment: @anonymossi Can you update your question with the lists values? Without this we can't really help you better than this

Answer (score -1):

`np.savetxt` saves arrays to text. So either convert the result to a list and use:

```
np.savetxt('test',[x])
```

or simply save the result to a regular text file:

```
with open( 'file.py', 'w' ) as datafile:
    datafile.write(x)
```

another popular method is [pickling](https://www.jessicayung.com/how-to-use-pickle-to-save-and-load-variables-in-python/).

also a couple of things to note:

you need to use `:` after the definition of your function. You should use `x=cal(a,b,c)` instead of saving the print to a variable.

Comment: no i need to use the local variable z for out side the function ...is it possible

Comment: @anonymossi if you need to use it outside simply save the result like this: `nonlocal_z = cal(1,2,3)` and replace `1,2,3` with whatever you want